# Python metaclass __init__ method gets called when creating child classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, init, metaclass

So I'm learning how python metaclass works. I have the following define a metaclass:

```
class XMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print('yrdy!')
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

Then creating a real class

```
X = XMeta('X', (), {})
```

What confuses me is when inheritance comes in:

```
class Y(X):
    pass
```

Then the print statements gets called, `yrdy!` gets printed. When you trying to create another child class:

```
class Z(X):
    pass
```

`yrdy!` gets printed again.

So my question is, if we consider `X` as an instance, since `X` is already gets defined and initialized, when creating class `Z`, why would `Xmeta.__init__` gets called again?

Comment: If `Z` doesn't define it's own `__init__` then it gets called following the MRO for the class so in this case you end up calling metaclasse's `__init __` i guess.

Comment: interesting, I know in this case `X.__init__` would gets called as `Z` does not define it's own `__init__`. But I haven't, at least explicitly, defined `X.__init__`, so how does `XMeta.__init__` gets called instead? I mean consider they don't have same number of parameters...

Comment: If you print MRO for Z you get the following: `[__main__.Z, __main__.X, object]` so if a method is called and Z doesn't define it, then the method is first checked in `X` and then in `object` in which case the meta-classe's init should get called as X is an instance of it.

Comment: @pavel: this is the metaclass we are talking about, and its `__init__` has nothing to do with the ordinary class ( `X`) ' `__init__`. This one would run when a class is instantiated. The metaclass' method is called when a class is _created_, either through the execution of a `class` statement, or by calling a metaclass programatically, (like (type(..., ..., ...) or XMeta(..., ..., ...) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaclasses `__new__` and `__init__` methods will be called for every class that uses them, and all classes in Python will always use the most derived metaclass in its superclasses.

That means, most of the time, any metaclass inserted in an inheritance chain will be used to create a child class.

That differs from the behavior, for example, of a class decorator (like `@dataclass`), which only affects the decorated class.

Continuing on your text "X" is an instance, yes, but an instance of the metaclass. When you inherit from it on Y, it is not "consumed", it is used as one of the base classes for the new class you are creating. The language spec determines them that its metaclass will be used when creating `Y`. Do not mistake inheting from "X" with creating new instances of "X", which is what happen when you call `X()`:  in this case there is no `__init__` method in the class itself, and nothing will be run.

Note that *even* if you'd create Y deriving from X programatically by calling the 3 argument form of `type`, since the rule is to use the most derived metaclass from all the bases, `XMeta` would still be used (and its `__init__` method run):

```
In [11]: class XMeta(type):
    ...:     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    ...:         print('yrdy!')
    ...:         super().__init__(name, bases, dct)
    ...: 

In [12]: X = XMeta('X', (), {})
yrdy!

In [13]: Y = type('Y', (X,), {})
yrdy!
```